# String.Replace not replacing vbCrlf

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of "\n" in the Text property of an ASP.NET TextBox with  <br /> using String.Repalce function, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
taEmailText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

As a solution I am using Regex.Replace:

```
New Regex("\n").Replace(taEmailText.Text, "<br />")
```

My question is why String.Replace can't find "\n" for me, even though this solution has been proposed on many sites and it has worked for many people.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET string objects are immutable, so [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) returns a new string with the replacement. You need to assign the result:

```
taEmailText.Text = taEmailText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

Also, rather than creating a new [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) object—when you do need a regular expression—then there are [static methods available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement)
```

---

Edit (based on comment):

Just tested this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim result As String = "One\nTwo".Replace("\n", "<br />")
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub
```

and the result is:

```
One<br />Two
```

Comment: Hi Richard, this is what I am doing: 
`Dim result As String = taEmailText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />")`.
I am not getting the result with <br /> in it. This is bizzare.

Comment: @Irfan: See test (I suggest you repeat this -- a VB Console App template): I suspect that `taEmailText.Text` doesn't have the value you expect.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try that in a fresh console application. Just a thought that if taEmailText.Text doesn't have a value I suspect, how come Regex.Replace can find it.

Comment: @Irfan: That's a good question. I would suspect the special handling that the regex engine applies to end of line characters (see multi-line vs. single-line matching mode).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the result of the method call is immediated forgotten. You should read [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) a bit more carefully:

> Returns **a new string** in which all occurrences…

Hence do:

```
taEmailText.Text = taEmailText.Text.Replace("\n", "<br />")
```

Comment: Hi Ondrej, Getting the result back in the TextBox is any different from getting it in a new string variable. I am using a new string var on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace does not change the content of the input string. It returns newly created string.
2. You might want to replace both \r and \n or use `Environment.NewLine` constant.

   ```
   var replacedText = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
   ```

Comment: Hi Alex, I am using a string variable on the left hand side to get the result. I just forgot to mention it in the question. I have tried \r\n as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does textbox has `TextMode="MultiLine"` attribute?

Comment: Yes. This is how it looks like: 
`<asp:TextBox Width="510" ID="taEmailText" Runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="80"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Werid. I copy/pasted your text box, entered 3 lines and I can see this in the debugger `taEmailText.Text = "line1\r\nline2\r\nline3"`. So after the replace it looks like this `line1<br />line2<br />line3`.